# Angular5 router-outlet in a child route won't render component consistently even if the url is correct

Tags: angular5, angular-router, router-outlet

I have a nested routing object in one of my modules with router-outlets for child-routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'portal',
      component: Portal
    },
      children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'meetings', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'meetings', component: MeetingsListComponent,
          children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'points', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'points', component: PointsListComponent},
            { path: 'point/:id', component: PointComponent}
          ] 
        }
      ]
    }
];
```

The MeetingsListComponent has a tab-menu with days of the week, and for each day it renders a list of meetings as accordion-elements. If user opens an accordion, this is wehere the nested router-outlet of the MeetingsListComponent renders the list of agenda points as a datatble: PointsListComponent. If user clicks on a datable row, the PointComponent should be rendered with detailed view of one agenda point:

```
onRowClick(e) {
    this.router.navigate(['../point', e.value.obj.id], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

The following happens:
the url-path in the browser switches from :

```
http://localhost:4200/portal/meetings/points
```

to

```
http://localhost:4200/portal/meetings/point/24fc3f42-7898-4044-9e24-511460d2001d
```

which is correct.

But weirdly, the PointComponent is being rendered only "sometimes". If I click on the menu tab and the data-set is changed for today, or tomorrow, the datatable is rendered, but by clicking on the row the url changes without the PointComponent being rendered in the router-outlet.

However, if I go to some other day in the tab menu, clicking on the same component (datable row) renders the detailed view, the PointComponent in the router-outlet. Nothing is different, it's the same component filled with other data, that's all.

So, the router navigate event seems to work properly, but the router-outlet doesn't do it:

[Here is a short vid of the routing error in action](https://www.useloom.com/share/b6b2f5da318c45c0a25a788cb13199c3)

I need to get to the bottom of this issue.